# VS 2019 tabular model shows blank values

Tags: azure, visual-studio, ssas

I am working with azure analysis services , the tabular grid view shows blank values but showing all values in the power query editor. I have vs 2019 community working with sql server 2019 and compatibility level 1500. The power query editor shows all values but the values in the grids are blank.

Comment: Have you processed the whole cube (Process All)?

Comment: Process default

Comment: Try Process all. Does it help?